# Why are both if and else conditions getting called in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

My problem is regarding using delegation, `.on();`

I've looked around and cannot find information here at stackoverflow for a possible solution to my problem.

Both of the conditions in my click event are getting fired or do not get fired at all. I've tried switching the conditions, and still both fire or don't fire at all, and I'm not sure why.

The current jQuery provided will not fire at all. If I remove or comment out all the code inside the else statement and add console.log('test') as a test, then you will see that both get fired.

Would someone be so kind and help me with what the problem is? Unfortunately I cannot simulate the environment through jsfiddle because this is a drupal site behind VPN, with a heck of a lot of dependencies.

The jQuery is as follows:

```
        // Depth 1 Menu Controls
        $('nav #block-superfish-1').on('click', 'li.menuparent.sf-depth-1 div.mobilesubnavarrow', function(){

            if(!$(this).hasClass('sf-expanded')){

                // Global
                $('li.menuparent.sf-depth-1').removeClass('sf-expanded');
                $('li.menuparent.sf-depth-1 div.mobilesubnavarrow').removeClass('sf-expanded');
                $('li.menuparent.sf-depth-1').find('ul').css({display: 'none'});

                $(this).addClass('sf-expanded');
                $(this).closest('li.menuparent.sf-depth-1').addClass('sf-expanded');
                $(this).closest('li.menuparent.sf-depth-1').find('ul').slideDown();

                return;
            } else {

                //$(this).removeClass('sf-expanded');
                $(this).closest('li.menuparent.sf-depth-1').removeClass('sf-expanded');
                $(this).closest('li.menuparent.sf-depth-1').find('ul').slideUp();
            }

        });
```

I also have another of the exact same jQuery for a 'Depth 2', with the only thing changing is the class `.sf-depth-2`, so there's no point in posting that here as well.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Move `return;` to the end of the function, and change it to `return false;`.  Do both conditions still fire?

Comment: actually you'd be better using `Event.preventDefault();` instead of unnecessary `return`s.

Comment: We can't help much without fiddle.

Comment: Both conditions can't possibly fire. Doesn't matter that drupal is involved, nothing preventing you copying  browser source code and creating a demo that replicates this with ultra basic css

Comment: @charlietfl, you are right - typically it doesn't matter if it's Drupal or any other CMS, but this project is put together with spaghetti code. I'm just trying to fix an issue the original developer created by making this overly complex. I'll try to pull out as much code as I can and put together a good jsfiddle that shows the problem.

Comment: Updated answer - if the project uses spaghetti code, check the rendered markup and ensure the script is not included twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simplified fiddle of your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/f6f2j319/

The code above seems to work as expected.
If the code doesn't fire at all I would suggest you check that the correct jQuery selector has been specified:

`li.menuparent.sf-depth-1 div.mobilesubnavarrow` inside the `nav #block-superfish-1`

(Also check the structure of your markup to ensure the correct order of divs...compare it to my Fiddle)

Both the `if` and `else` statements shouldn't be firing together...it's possible that the function is firing twice in quick succession but it's hard to say without seeing more of your code.

**Check that your script is not included twice on the page** (especially if it contains spaghetti code).

I've also included a fiddle with the comment in the `else` statement uncommented:
https://jsfiddle.net/k14oumfe/

This seems like the behaviour you require.

Let me know if this isn't the case.

Comment: Thank you Alvin Pascoe for taking the time to create two jsfiddles. Both your solutions work great. I wish you all the best.

Comment: @ScriptsConnect - No problem, I'm glad they helped!